# Overriding a Get/Set Property to Be Get-Only Still Lets You Set It

Tags: c#, properties, overriding, accessor

Consider this short example:

```
class Program
{
    private abstract class PropertyExample
    {
        public virtual bool Property { get; set; }
    }

    private class GetOnlyProperty : PropertyExample
    {
        private bool property = false;
        public override bool Property => property;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetOnlyProperty example = new GetOnlyProperty();
        example.Property = true;
    }
}
```

Even though I overrode `Property` in the `GetOnlyProperty` class to be get-only, I am still able to set it in `Main()`. Why is this possible?

Comment: Don't override, mark it as `new`

Comment: @MohamedAhmed That still wouldn't remove the ability to set the property value.

Comment: He can't with the current `example` object of type `GetOnlyProperty`

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Have you tried executing it? Works for me; that's why I submitted the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the generated CIL code, it turns out that your are overriding the getter method by makking it read only in the derived class:

```
public override bool Property => property;
```

but still inheriting the setter, so when you set the property, you still have access to the setter method of the base class.

Answer (score 2):

The language cannot allow you to do what you are attempting to accomplish here.  The Liskov Substitution Principle requires that a derived class be substitutable anywhere that a base class is expected.  For that property to hold true, every accessible member of the base class interface must exist and be accessible in the derived class.

Comment: So why does the compiler not issue a warning or error? An oversight maybe?

Comment: @DomnWerner -Maybe, although with the syntax you chose it's not entirely clear you intended to override the setter method.

Comment: Are you saying that I am only overriding only the getter? It was my understanding that I was overriding the property itself.

Comment: @DomnWerner - When you override a property you have to specify which parts you are overriding - getter or setter.  Anything you don't override is left as-is.